# Left join table with duplicate value in the key column

Tags: mysql, sql, duplicates, left-join

For dataset a

| name | height | weight |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Pen | 155 | 45 |
| Leo | 172 | 50 |
| Dan | 180 | 60 |

Dataset b

| name | nation | age | date of birth |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Pen | China | 22 | 15/10/1998 |
| Pen | Italy | 30 | 19/08/1990 |
| Pen | Italy | 30 | 30/01/1990 |
| NULL | Japan | 27 | 12/09/1993 |

I try to use the following code to join two data:

```sql
Select * From a
JOIN b
ON a.name = b.name;
```

How can I change my code so that I can keep everything on the a table by joining the name column in both dataset and also shows all the null value if it exists?

Comment: Try `Select * From a RIGHT JOIN b ON a.name = b.name;`

Comment: What is your expected output?

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please see [Why should I provide an MCRE for what seems to me to be a very simple SQL query](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query)

Answer (score 0):

The traditional way is to use an [outer join](https://www.tutorialgateway.org/mysql-left-join/).

```
Select * 
From a LEFT OUTER JOIN b ON a.name = b.name
```

You don't need to specify OUTER, as "LEFT JOIN" will be the same in MySQL.

```
Select * 
From a LEFT JOIN b ON a.name = b.name
```

Use whichever syntax you like, although in my opinion, adding the "OUTER" makes it clear to anyone reading the SQL that it's an outer join rather than an inner join.

Comment: Do you have an example of an RDBMS where LEFT JOIN does not mean LEFT OUTER JOIN?

Comment: You make a good point there, I couldn't find any RDBMS that assume an inner join using LEFT or RIGHT nor does it really make sense.  I removed that portion of the answer.

Answer (score 0):

Following simple join on the name field can help you with that

> `SELECT * FROM a LEFT JOIN b ON a.name = b.name`